# How to switch locales/languages for different users

Tags: yii, translation, yii-extensions, yii-modules

I have designed a web application, It works for two different users say `user1` and `user2`, and both of the users need the `view` in different languages.

I have studied about `yii:t()` but by that method we have to define language in `main.config`, which set the same language for both users.

How can I translate my view in different languages for both users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can help you:
you need to edit urlmanager.php in your components, if there is no file, you need to create one.

Check this url: [Multilingual](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/)

Thanks.

Comment: Hey coder, I was working on that link, when I click on any link of language in my UI, then it gives an error like, url :site/logout not found, my url is at ?r=site/logout, what should I do for that

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your **SiteController.php**:

```
public function actionChangeLocale($locale) {

    // (OPTIONAL) if is registered user (not guest), save preferred locale in database 
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {

        // Update user settings
        $uid = Yii::app()->user->id;
        User::model()->updateByPk($uid, array('locale' => $locale));
    }

    // change locale
    Yii::app()->user->setState('_locale', $locale);

    // redirect to previous page, in the new locale
    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
        $referrer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    else
        $referrer = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) . '/';

    $this->redirect($referrer);
}
```

Edit your **main.php** config url manager rules:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
             'lang/<id:\w+>' => 'site/changeLocale',
```

To change locale, create a link to point user to desired locale:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/lang/en
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/lang/zh
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/lang/ja
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/lang/in
...
```

If you saved the logged-in user's preferred locale in database, add this to **SiteController.php** Login action:

```
    $uid = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $user = User::model()->findbypk($uid);

    $userLocale = isset($user->locale) ? $model->locale : Yii::app()->language;
    Yii::app()->user->setState('_locale', $userLocale);
```

Above usage is for those using htaccess rewrite. Make sure base **.htaccess** file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] # Remove trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Related Articles:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

Related Modules:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ei18n/

Comment: Hey Sameuel, when I am using url http://localhost/Snitch-appointpress/Appointpress/lang/en then I am getting error The requested URL /Snitch-appointpress/Appointpress/lang/en was not found on this server.